# Why bring a multitool on long treks?

Tags: gear, trekking

I have been trekking for years now, mostly in Scandinavia, Canada and Peru. For most of treks we had to be sustainable and carry food for 10-14 days at a time - so weight is always a big issue.

Obviously this requires very optimized equipment, and for this reason I never considered bringing a multitool (like a [swisstool](http://www.victorinox.com/ch/category/Swiss-Army-Knives/1008?f=category&v=1/100/1008&m=add&) or [leatherman](http://www.leatherman.co.uk)): personally I just never saw the benefit of such a tool, as out in the wild I essentially never encountered situations that would call for pliers, screwdrivers, or any of the other sophisticated tools.

However, over the years I have seen plenty of people who absolutely swear by their multitools and bring them on every occasion, including long hikes or trekking trips.

I'd like to know of you:

- Why do you bring your multitool on long trips?
- What kinds of purposes does it serve, which a normal knife can't?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's always a difference between required and excessive. A lot of these multi tools have specific purposes. Do I require a screwdriver on a trek?  Mostly no. Will I use a knife, a pair of scissors or even a pair of tweezers? Mostly Yes.

So do I recommend carrying a multi tool to a trek? Yes. But having said that, there are multitude of these tools out there. What one needs to look at is the one which makes sense for a trek. I have multitools which have the basic knife-scissor-tweezer-pin combination and also another one with a screwdriver-plier combination. I do not carry the screwdriver ones on treks. They are heavy and pretty much useless.

What all have I used my multi tools for?

- Cutting fruits, opening cans, opening up packed food.
- Removing thorns from my fingers using tweezers.
- Sewing up my shoes with reamer (a temporary but useful solution).

On a lighter note, once when I was on a forest survey, I met a fellow who felt his swiss multi tool knife could provide him sufficient protection against wild animals. So yeah, for some, it might give some mental strength as well :D ;)

EDIT:

What a normal knife can't? That  would be a very selective list. And probably one could argue that pretty much everything could be achieved using a normal knife with sufficient skill. Personally I do not use a bigger knife for delicate stuff like removing a splinter ;). Also, I've met folks who do not carry a knife (mostly those going for guided treks) and prefer multi tool instead. I also believe that the human tendency to feel more comfortable with more options has to do with this somehow.

Comment: In Canada you can also use the tweezers to remove ticks which may carry the [Lyme disease](http://healthycanadians.gc.ca/diseases-conditions-maladies-affections/disease-maladie/lyme/surveillance-eng.php).

Comment: Tick removal is also a major concern in the northeastern USA.

Comment: Are you guys saying that there aren't ticks in other parts of the world?

Comment: There are ticks in Europe too, and they can also carry nasty diseases.

Comment: You use tweezers to remove ticks?!   You are just begging to burst the body and leave the head inside the wound.  As a Team Medic I am imploring you stop doing this and invest in a tick removal tool ($3).  If you must use tweezers there is a dedicated technique.  http://www.bada-uk.org/correct-tick-removal/tick-removal-fine-tipped-tweezers

Answer (score 5):

I carry a compact [Victorinox Swiss Army Knife (Huntsman)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/sports/dp/B0001P151W) which I find perfectly adequate for all of the situations I have encountered in the wilderness.

If you consider that too heavy to carry (3.5 inches and 28grams) then you need to reevaluate your fitness (joke!) and what kind of trade-offs you are making between weight and functionality.

As an ex-soldier I know plenty of guys who swear by huge industrial leatherman tools but I have never felt they were particularly more efficient.

Here are my primary reasons;

- The UK has very stringent laws regarding knives; it's not worth owning a larger variant
- I will always need to cut paracord or tape or bandages so a small blade is fine
- I often strip sticks for the kids into items/poles
- I have sawn down small foliage for various reasons
- I have used the bottle opener several times ;-)
- I have whittled poles to slot into the eyeholes of the tarp
- I have used the tweezers quite a few times

But ultimately it is really the idea that I would rather have a small, useful utility tool in my packing list and not need than the other way about.

If I was trekking the Appalachian Trail or the Rockies I would probably invest in a large, suitable knife because you are correct; 90% of the actions involve cutting, sawing, stripping or the blade portion in some way but for the UK and most of Europe a Swiss Army Knife is perfectly adequate.

The limitation of a multi-tool versus a knife is the force you can bring to bare through the handle of a knife as a hammer-like strike (tent pegs, stakes, general all-round man smashing of stuff).